# CALayer compositingFilter, iOS 5 and CoreImage

Tags: ios5, core-graphics, calayer, blend

The API Docs for CALayer state:  (I'm not sure if the docs are up to date??)

> compositingFilter A CoreImage filter used to composite the receiver’s
>   contents with the background. Animatable.
>
> @property(retain) id compositingFilter
>
> ...
>
> Special Considerations While the CALayer class exposes this property,
>   Core Image is not available in iOS. Currently the filters available
>   for this property are undefined.

But CoreImage IS available on iOS5, so could I add a CoreImage filter to a CALayer and add that layer to another layer and expect it to work?

I want to add a sublayer to a layer and have it use a specific blend mode (multiply).  I can't figure out how to do this otherwise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although the docs have not been revised, and although Core Image is now partially available in iOS, only a tiny bit of its functionality is present. CALayer compositing filter, background filters, and so forth, are among the things that are *not* present. So you should go on ignoring the `compositingFilter` property.

Comment: Damn. I was hoping they would be :(

Comment: Me too :) But both experimentation and the WWDC 2011 videos are very clear about this... iOS devices just don't have that kind of computing power.

Comment: well i guess the question now is, how can i fade the edges of a table view's content to nothing.  i.e. i have an image as a background of my table view, so i can't just add a gradient layer over top because then you wouldn't see the background.  I want to create a gradient alpha mask that is using multiply blend mode over top of the content of the tablecells.  Did that make sense? :D

Comment: What I would do is paint the individual cells with their edges fading as you describe. Give the cell's background view the gradient alpha mask you describe.

Comment: in the end I followed [a tutorial](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/08/adding-fading-gradients-to-uitableview/) that basically got me there.

Comment: That tutorial is wrong, @horseshoe7. He keeps *saying* the word "mask" but what he comes up with in the end is not a mask at all; he's just covering the top and bottom of the table view with white. That's not the same as what a true mask would do, which is to make the top and bottom of the table view transparent and let what's *beneath* it show through. His first solution was closer to being right.

Comment: In fact, he almost had it right when he said "You can always move to the view’s superview and add it there, but this is considered bad form, a view should only fiddle with it’s own descendants." It is *not* considered bad form. Masking the superview's layer with a true layer mask is exactly the correct solution.

Comment: @matt, I was looking for help on exactly what you mentioned about needing transparent mask on the top and bottom on a tableview. I didn't want to hijack this post with my own questions so I [posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9105773/uitableview-with-transparent-gradient-at-top-and-bottom) my own. I appreciate the help.

Comment: I'm voting you up, but in my heart I'm voting Apple down.

Comment: `compositingFilter` is still not available, despite being a view property on iOS?

Comment: Not sure about 2011 when this answer was made but in 2019 *some* of the most commonly used blending modes are readily available for iOS https://github.com/arthurschiller/CompositingFilters

Comment: @DesmondHume That’s unofficial and unsupported so far.